# Problem with AudioToolBox when build for iOS Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have some kind of error..
when try to build for iphone device i recieve this warning with errors

```
ld: warning: ignoring file psydevdocs/IphoneProjects/Qwave/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_AudioQueueGetProperty", referenced from:
      -[AudioQueueObject isRunning] in AudioQueueObject.o
  "_AudioQueueStart", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalAnalyzer record] in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
      -[AudioSignalGenerator play] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
      -[AudioSignalGenerator resume] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioQueueDispose", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalAnalyzer dealloc] in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
      -[AudioSignalGenerator dealloc] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioSessionSetActive", referenced from:
      -[QWaveSJViewController listenBytes:] in QWaveSJViewController.o
  "_AudioQueueStop", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalAnalyzer stop] in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
      -[AudioSignalGenerator stop] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer", referenced from:
      _recordingCallback in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
      -[AudioSignalAnalyzer setupRecording] in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
      _playbackCallback in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioQueueNewInput", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalAnalyzer init] in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
  "_AudioQueueSetParameter", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalGenerator setupPlaybackAudioQueueObject] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioQueuePause", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalGenerator pause] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioQueueNewOutput", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalGenerator setupPlaybackAudioQueueObject] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
  "_AudioQueueAllocateBuffer", referenced from:
      -[AudioSignalAnalyzer setupRecording] in AudioSignalAnalyzer.o
      -[AudioSignalGenerator setupAudioQueueBuffers] in AudioSignalGenerator.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Somebody which have an idea where is the error ? Thanks

Comment: Did u add the AudioToolBox Frame work?

Comment: yes,she is include with other frameworks, i think that have some problem with armv6 or armv7 architecture